# Mailchimp css helper classes

Tags: css, mailchimp, helper

I want to add table cell (td) padding using the helper class padding--lv1, according the documentation.
https://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/helpers

I have the following html but, the css class doesn't work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="padding--lv6">AAA</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: are you 100% the MailChimp css is being included in your file? It may help to see more code or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: I am using the template editor from Mailchimp

Comment: ah, yes that makes sense. Sorry, not really familiar with their tools.